# Are the firebase Transactions method compatible with all writing operations, including cloud function's writing operations?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I know how Transactions  works, as it performs operations atomically and prevents racing between users
But my question is will this be on any operations written on Firestore, whether they are from users or from Cloud Functions?

**steps**

1- the following is cloud function operation , it write to Firstore (boolen value) to the `isAcar field` and docUID is `123`,
in the following write i don't care for any condition write

```js
  exports.onUserStatusChanged = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}').onUpdate(
    async (change, context) => {
      const eventStatus = change.after.val();
      const userStatusFirestoreRef = firestore.doc(`users/${context.params.uid}`);
      return userStatusFirestoreRef.update(eventStatus);
  });
```

2- the following is in the app client

```dart
 myFunction(){
  DocumentReference doc = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc('123');
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
    DocumentSnapshot docVal = await transaction.get(doc );
    if (docVal.get('isAcar ')==false) {
      transaction.update(doc ,{
    'isAcar ':true, 
  });
    }
  });
}
```

Is the write operation in the second code atomic? or must i also use transection in cloud function write operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) either from the client or from the Cloud Functions.

Comment: thanks . just to make sure if you get what i meant exactly or not . i don't use Transection in cloud function part , it only write direct to Firestore without any condition or transection .  the only place i use the transection is in the app according to the cloud function writes values as conditions . same answer?

Comment: If you're updating the same value in Firestore, from both client and Cloud Functions, then you definitely need to use transactions in both places. If a Cloud Function only **adds** data and the listener fires on the client to inform you that, and right after that you are using a transaction, then you don't have to use a transaction in Cloud Functions.

Comment: kindly can you take a look to my edits .

Comment: As said before, if both operations are updating the exact same `isAcar` field, yes, you also have to use transactions in Cloud Functions. And to answer the first question, by definition transaction operations are atomic.

Comment: thanks Alex mamo , i appreciate that , but i still don't understand why must i need to use transection in cloud function If basically  there is no concern about writing operations in cloud function write ..because it writes Boolean values for who made the paid subscription for example  to firestore ... In return, the user verifies if his name is as a subscriber or not in firestore (transection part - second code) . i don't understand why i need to make transection and condition in cloud function part

Comment: If the user updates only the information that belongs to him, and there cannot be multiple operations on the exact same field and at the exact same time, then I don't see any reason why would you use transactions in client code in the first place. Besides that, transactions don't work offline. Transactions are useful in a multi-user environment when multiple users can update the value of a field at the exact same time. For example, when multiple users can update a counter.

Comment: i see ,to make it simple you can imagine cloud function performs continuous writes to firestore for a minute (once true once false per sec to isAcar Field ) . at the same time i chick the results to same field  in transection in app client . Are all queries going to be atomic at this minute?. that's it . and sorry for making it long . i only want to understand this point

Comment: If there is a chance that a function (during that minute) can update the value of the field at the exact same time the application does, then you have to use transactions in both places. Otherwise, you can have inconsistent data.

Comment: thank you so mush Alex . now i understand . and must i use condition with the transection too ? or just transaction.update({isAcar:false}) (in cloud function part) ? because i have no required condition there .

Comment: If there is nothing to check, then there is no need to use an if statement. You can update it directly.

Comment: ''You can update it directly.'' .. like transaction.update({isAcar:false}) . yes?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's correct.

Comment: sorry for taking long because i was having some issues in login thanks a lot Alex mamo .. i don't know what to do if you did not offer these awesome information to me .. everything walking fine now ♥